# Import GPS data (text documents files) to QGis

Tags: qgis, gps, file-formats, import, text

I want to import GPS data (text document files) in to Qgis, what  file format are you suppose to use ?

Comment: Welcome to SE.GIS forum. Please go though quick tutorial http://courses.umass.edu/nrc297s/PDFs/Mapping_GPS_points_using_QGIS.pdf

Answer (score 2):

GPS data usually comes as GPX files, and QGIS is able to import that format with the built-in GPS Tools.

Comment: In this case my gps data are .txt files, is it possible to convert to GPX files or import as .txt files direct ?

Comment: If the text file has the XML structure of a GPX file, you can still use the GPS Tools. If the data is in a tabular format, use the delimited text import from the Add layer menu. The only thing that does not work is data in degrees-minutes-seconds format. It has to be decimal degrees, but every spreadsheet programm should be able to compute that.